# Standalone Wiremock + Used port

Tags: java, integration-testing, wiremock

I'm new to wiremock, and I'm trying to use it to record the requests & responses of a java application I'm responsible for integration testing.

I know my command will resemble:
`java -jar wiremock-1.57-standalone.jar --port 9080 -proxy-all="http://search.twitter.com" --record-mappings --verbose`

Port 9080 is the port that my java application is running on, and sends api traffic through.

However, the above command doesn't work because of a java.net.BindException: Address already in use. This makes sense to me, as both the java app and Wiremock are both trying to use the same port.

Therefore, how would I record the api calls with Wiremock?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The port option in the command is for wiremock to run.So you have to give another free port.If you are using some security apis,try to give --https-port also.It starts on both ports.

Answer (score 1):

Wiremock standalone server should be started on separate port. Once both wiremock server and your application are up, you can goto recorder page http://wiremock_server_hort:wiremock_server_port/__admin/recorder and add ur API's link in target URL. Hit API's end point that you want to record and then you will get the mappings in 'mappings' folder (folder will be at same location where wiremock JAR is placed). For further detail check: http://wiremock.org/docs/record-playback/

Answer (score 0):

the port is already in use, so change the port on the command line.

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, can you please accept it?